# Build string for SQL statement with multiple checkboxes in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, string, if-statement

I am currently working with a SQL back end and vb.net Windows Forms front end. I am trying to pull a report from SQL based on a list of checkboxes the user will select.

To do this I am going to use an `IN` clause in SQL. The only problem is if I use an if statement in vb.net to build the string its going to be a HUGE amount of code to set up the string.

I was hoping someone knew a better way to do this. The code example below shows only selecting line 1 and selecting both line 1 and 2. I will need for the code to be able to select any assortment of the lines. The string will have to be the line number with a comma following the number. This way when I include the code in my SQL query it will not bug.

Here is the code:

```
Dim LineString As String
    'String set up for line pull
    If CBLine1.Checked = False And CBLine2.Checked = False And CBLine3.Checked = False And CBLine4.Checked = False And _
         CBLine7.Checked = False And CBLine8.Checked = False And CBLine10.Checked = False And CBLine11.Checked = False And CBLine12.Checked = False Then
        MsgBox("No lines selected for download, please select lines for report.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If CBLine1.Checked = True And CBLine2.Checked = False And CBLine3.Checked = False And CBLine4.Checked = False And _
        CBLine7.Checked = False And CBLine8.Checked = False And CBLine10.Checked = False And CBLine11.Checked = False And CBLine12.Checked = False Then
        MsgBox("This will save the string as only line 1")

    ElseIf CBLine1.Checked = True And CBLine2.Checked = True And CBLine3.Checked = False And CBLine4.Checked = False And _
    CBLine7.Checked = False And CBLine8.Checked = False And CBLine10.Checked = False And CBLine11.Checked = False And CBLine12.Checked = False Then
        MsgBox("This will save the string as only line 1 and 2")
    End If
```

The final string will have to be inserted into a SQL statement that looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabl1 
WHERE LineNumber IN (-vb.netString-)
```

The above code will need commas added in for the string.

Comment: Why do you check all checkboxes at one time? What if you'll construct the result string on the fly by checking state of each control successively, one by one?

Comment: @RuslanGaripov so your saying have a public string and change it on a checkbox change event?

Comment: No. You can rebuild the string to be injected to `where` clause on demand. Once user click on a checkbox, your code rebuilds the string and passes it to SQL command.

Comment: @RuslanGaripov Ok, I will try that, but how do i rebuild the string without running a million if statements to build it. As in, how can I say IF line1.checked = true then add it to the string, IF line2.checked = true then add it to the string and if not checked how to remove it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have large experience with VB-coding, but I'll try to explain. Assume you have result string: `Dim sz As String`. You check state of the first checkbox: `if (cb1.checked) then "add to sz #1, "`. Then you check state of the second control as follow: "if (cb2.checked) then "add to sz #2, "". And so on. Don't forget to remove trailing ", " on the end of the result string.

Comment: You can create a container ("collection" in VB-terms?) where you store references to the check-box controls. Then you simply iterate over the container, building the result string -- you add an item index as "line number". Thus you can avoid many if-s in your code.

Comment: I believe [`StringBuilder` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides interface for you to build string at run-time in VB.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to set up all your checkboxes with the Tag property set to the line number to which they refers. So, for example, the CBLine1 checkbox will have its property Tag set to the value 1 (and so on for all other checkboxes).

This could be done easily using the WinForm designer or, if you prefer, at runtime in the Form load event.

Next step is to retrieve all the checked checkboxes and extract the Tag property to build a list of lines required. This could be done using some Linq

```
Dim linesSelected = new List(Of String)()
For Each chk in Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)().
                   Where(Function(c) c.Checked)
   linesSelected.Add(chk.Tag.ToString())
Next
```

Now you could start your verification of the input

```
if linesSelected.Count = 0 Then
   MessageBox.Show("No lines selected for download, please select lines for report.")
Else If linesSelected.Count = 1 Then
   MessageBox.Show("This will save the string only for line " & linesSelected(0))
Else
   Dim allLines = string.Join(",", linesSelected)
   MessageBox.Show("This will save the string for lins " & allLines)
End If
```

Of course, the List(Of String) and the string.Join method are very good to build also your IN clause for your query

Comment: Let me give this a go, it seems like its almost exactly what i'm looking for.

Comment: This appears to work without adding the sql statement, but I am a bit confused on how the code works. I will have to do some research on how the function and tag code works. Thanks so much steve.

Comment: The Linq in the For Each means, give me a sequence of controls of type checkbox, then apply at this sequence the WHERE method and filter the sequence with only the checkbox for which the method returns true. The WHERE method runs, on every checkbox, the anonymous function that receives one by one the checkboxes and returns true if the checkbox is checked or false if not.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that I'm only half getting your question but I hope this helps. In VB.net we display a list of forms that have a status of enabled or disabled.

There is a checkbox that when checked displays only the enabled forms.

```
SELECT * FROM forms WHERE (Status = 'Enabled' or @checkbox = 0)
```

The query actually has a longer where  clause that handles drop down options in the same way. This should help you pass the backend VB to a simple SQL statement.

Comment: I am not sure how status works. I am unfamiliar with what your saying.

Answer (score -1):

```
If checkboxes 3...10 = false then
    If checkbox 1 = true then
        If checkbox 2 is true then
            A
        Else if checkbox 2 = false then
            B
        End if
Else
    C
End if
```